# Universal Reference: Cannot convert parameter from 'int' to 'int &&'

Tags: c++, c++11

I am running all code below in VS 2015 Community Edition.

I am getting error in my code when I attempt to implement a suggestion that was suggested to me in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148298/thread-safe-circular-queue-implementation). The part that I am having trouble with is changing the arguments to `TryPush` to be `TryPush(T&& val)`.

```
#pragma once

#include <atomic>
#include <memory>


template <typename T> class RingBuffer {
public:

   /*
   Other functions
   */

    void Push(T val) {
        while (!TryPush(val));
    }

private:

   /*
   Other functions
   */

    //Private Member Functions
    bool TryPush(T && val) {
        const std::size_t current_write = write_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        const std::size_t current_read = read_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        const std::size_t next_write = increment_index(current_write);

        if (next_write == current_read) { return false; }

        _ring_buffer_array[current_write] = std::move(val);
        write_position.store(next_write, std::memory_order_release);

        return true;
    }

    std::size_t increment_index(std::size_t index) {
        return (index + 1) % _buffer_capacity;
    }

    //Private Member Variables
    std::atomic<std::size_t> read_position = 0;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> write_position = 0;

    std::size_t _buffer_capacity;
    std::unique_ptr<T[], RingBufferFree> _ring_buffer_array;
};
```

Whenever I attempt to compile this code I get the following error **bool RingBuffer::TryPush(T &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &&**. What confuses me is that if change the code to

```
#pragma once

#include <atomic>
#include <memory>


template <typename T> class RingBuffer {
public:

   /*
   Other functions
   */

    void Push(T && val) {
        while (!TryPush(val));
    }

private:

   /*
   Other functions
   */

    //Private Member Functions
    bool TryPush(T val) {
        const std::size_t current_write = write_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        const std::size_t current_read = read_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        const std::size_t next_write = increment_index(current_write);

        if (next_write == current_read) { return false; }

        _ring_buffer_array[current_write] = std::move(val);
        write_position.store(next_write, std::memory_order_release);

        return true;
    }

    std::size_t increment_index(std::size_t index) {
        return (index + 1) % _buffer_capacity;
    }

    //Private Member Variables
    std::atomic<std::size_t> read_position = 0;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> write_position = 0;

    std::size_t _buffer_capacity;
    std::unique_ptr<T[], RingBufferFree> _ring_buffer_array;
};
```

It compiles and runs. I was under the impressions from Scott Meyer's [blog post](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) that `TryPush(T && val)` is a Universal reference and I should be able to use it as is shown in the first code snippet and then move the value into the array thus ensuring the code works regardless of whether an lvalue or rvalue is passed into the function. It seems to work if it the public facing `Push` method and thus I am sort of confused as to what is going on. I must be missing something here and was wondering if anybody could clarify what exactly it is. Thanks.

**Edit**
Called like so

```
RingBuffer<int> r(50);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    r.Push(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: How do you call `TryPush`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no universal references in your code. In the [blog post](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) you linked, see this similar example:

> ```
> template <class T, class Allocator = allocator<T> >
> class vector {
> public:
>     ...
>     void push_back(T&& x);       // fully specified parameter type ⇒ no type deduction;
>     ...                          // && ≡ rvalue reference
> };
> ```

To use this code you would write something like `vector<int> v; v.push_back(x);` , and the function is already known as taking `int&&` so there is no deduction.

Universal references only happen when the template type is being deduced from the argument (and they work because the type can be deduced as a reference type).

---

Your original code (with pass-by-value) would work fine, if you change `TryPush(val)` to `TryPush(std::move(val))`.  To eliminate unnecessary move operations you can provide two overloads, e.g.:

```
    void Push(T && val)     { while (!TryPush(std::move(val))); }
    void Push(T const& val) { while (!TryPush(val)); }
private:
    template<typename U>
    bool TryPush(U&& val)
    {
       // preparation logic...
        _ring_buffer_array[current_write] = std::forward<U>(val);
```

You could of course use two overloads `T const &` and `T&&` instead of a universal reference for `TryPush` , but then you'd have some code duplication across the two bodies.

Also you could even replace `Push` with:

```
template<typename U>
void Push(U&& val)
{
    while ( !TryPush(std::forward<U>(val)) ); 
}
```

Comment: Would this be the way in which you suggest setting it up then? Have two public facing methods `void Push(T && val) ` and `void Push(const T & val) ` which internally both call `bool TryPush(T val) `. Are there any concerns doing it this way?

Comment: @cogle I expanded the example

Comment: Shouldn't `std::forward(val)` be `std::forward<U>(val)`?

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to forward that is a seriously neat way of solving the problem.